# Create a BluetoothLEDevice from DeviceInformation?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uwp

Is it possible to create a BluetoothLEDevice from a DeviceInformation object? I've tried using the DeviceInformation's Id property in BluetoothLEDevice .FromIdAsync  however that just throws errors

```
    public static async Task<BluetoothLEDevice> DeviceFromDeviceInfo(DeviceInformation x)
    {
        try {
            string g = x.Id.Substring(x.Id.IndexOf("{") + 1);
            g = g.Remove(g.IndexOf("}"));
            return await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(g);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

This throws {"Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)"}

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same issue with a Heart Rate Device. With a regular Bluetooth (not LE) device your code should work once it's connected. However, with BTLE the goal is to discover the device without the user having to pair it first. I don't have an answer for that part. Using Windows 8.1 it wasn't possible [MSDN Forum Post (2014)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3b62bdbf-9a55-4c0f-becf-f4e91d4bc027/windows-8-bluetooth-le-and?forum=wdk), [MVP Blog Post (2014)](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2014/02/ble-for-windows-81-part-i.html), but I'm hoping it's possible with Windows 10 Universal Apps.

There are a lot of unanswered Bluetooth LE discovery and scanning posts on Stackoverflow which isn't encouraging. Hopefully we get an answer soon!

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows 10 still requires that LE devices are paired.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Carter!

Answer (score 0):

So long as the device you are trying to access is paired, you should be able to access it. I'm not sure why you're modifying the `Id`. To create the device all you need is:

```
DeviceInformation deviceInfo = __;
BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
```

Comment: I was trying this, however it was throwing an error saying the ID format was incorrect. Should it be parsing a full hardware ID or just the UUID/GUID?

Comment: It should be the full ID. Are you sure the deviceInfo represents a BluetoothLE device? Could I see how you are creating the DeviceInformation watcher?

Comment: Ok I think I found a problem I was having, I'll see if I can fix it myself

Comment: Sounds good :) For my curiosity, if you do have a fix, please let me know what it was.